# Error viewing order info on facebook payment

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, payment

This is extremely frustrating and facebook certainly doesn't provide any GOOD example documentation so I am hoping someone can help me.

I am trying to SIMPLY make a call to the facebook graph api to pull the details of a facebook payment order #.  Using the Graph API Explorer i am doing a call to /############ (the #### being the order number) and selecting the application from my app drop down list at the top to generate the app access token.  What I get back is an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 15
  }
}
```

When I dod an app access token lookup using the following call:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials

when I use the access token returned I get a different error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#15) This method is not supported for native apps",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 15
   }
}
```

I have checked the app and it is set to Desktop/Native as it is a game.  We take payments for the application so why I am not able to query the payments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook App Type: Which one to pick for mobile AND web?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11614064/facebook-app-type-which-one-to-pick-for-mobile-and-web)

Comment: I originally ran into the issue with our application set to native/desktop.  I have also tried it on our development app set to web app and now it returns "false".  I can't figure out if this is a bug or if there is something else needed

Comment: 'false' means privacy or visibility checks failed - are you getting 'false' on the call to fetch client_credentials? that shouldn't happen unless the app is deleted/invisible for some reason

Comment: So when I run the get request from the Graph API Explorer I am logged in as the application administrator, it gives me my list of apps, i select the one I want, and I put the order number on the GET line.  If I click GET ACCESS CODE and let the interface pull the APP ACCESS TOKEN and click submit I get an error saying I need an APP ACCESS TOKEN.  If I pull the ACCESS TOKEN my self using the process I outlined in my original post and use that as my access token and click submit, I get "false" returned.

Comment: It is like it wants me to have certain permissions but there aren't any specific for applications.  I am basically saying through the code.  I am the app show me what orders have been generated from me.  It should be a simple call yet it isn't

Comment: Are you sure the app access token you're using (see https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token for a helpful tool) is for the same app that the order was made with?

Comment: Hey Igy - thanks for that tool.  That is awesome.  I have been told the orders I am using came from the development site but I will go back and check.  The token I was using was the correct one so that is nice to see and that tool explained a few things to me that now make sense.

Comment: We just did a purchase on the dev site and pulled the order id number, used the correct app token and am still getting false.  Any other ideas?  this just seems bizarre.

Comment: Are you sure it's a real order that went through and was paid for? If it was one of your 'credits test users' the orders don't really exist and aren't accessible via the API - this is noted on the Order documentation

Comment: Well that might be our problem in Dev.  It is a tester's order.  I didn't see that in the Order documentation.  Thanks Igy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding as an answer to help anyone else that finds this question, if accessing an Order object in the Graph API is returning 'false', check the following:

1. The app is not set to 'native/desktop' (this setting is under advanced settings) - if so, the app access token is untrusted
2. The Order you're trying to access is a real order, not one of the Payments Test Users in the app settings

The first case is relatively little known, but is because 'native / desktop' apps are assumed to have distributed the app secret in the binary.

The second is mentioned near the top of the [Order](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/order/) object's documentation

Comment: Hey Igy.  that was exactly the issue.  Thanks.  We are moving along now.